# Display the labels of last 9 bars

Tags: pine-script

Currently I have this script [Plot only when defined condition is met in Pinescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76161207/plot-only-when-defined-condition-is-met-in-pinescript)

```
var int buySetup = na
buySetup := if close < close[4]
    if close[1] > close[5] or 0 < nz(buySetup[1])
        nz(buySetup[1]) + 1
    else
        0
else
    0

plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='9', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar)
plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='8', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, offset = -1)
plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='7', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, offset = -2)
plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='6', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, offset = -3)
plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='4', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, offset = -4)
plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='5', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, offset = -5)
plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='3', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, offset = -6)
plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='2', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, offset = -7)
plotchar(buySetup == 9, char='1', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, offset = -8)
```

This allows me to draw two more cards (haha jk). As i linked in the post above, this script only plots when buysetup has completed (when it has reached count 9). However, how do I adjust this code so that it keeps the features I have stated above, BUT plots the last 9 BARS on the current chart, regardless if it has finished its count or not?

Is this possible with "ta.barssince()"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to plot the last 9 bars on the current chart, regardless if it has finished or not, you can replace :

```
buySetup == 9
```

by

```
true
```

in your plotchar code lines

Comment: hi thanks again! But this wouldn't keep the previous feature though? What I want to do is  1) keep plotting when buycountdown has finished (count 9) EXCEPT 2) plot buycount for the LAST 9 bars from the current bar, regardless whether it has finished or not. Thanks